# Chai expect - expect(browser.getTitle()) errors with - browser.getTitle is not a function

Tags: javascript, protractor, chai, cucumberjs

I have the following code which uses Chai, but when executed fails and console returns **"TypeError: browser.getTitle is not a function."**
My path to Globals.js is correct because if I do something like this, it works - `expect('Test abc').toContain('abc')`. Please help.

```
const Globals = require('../utilities/Globals');
const browser = require('protractor');
const { Given } = require('cucumber');

// Chai
const globals = new Globals();
const expect = globals.expect;


Given('I am on google page with title {string}', function (title) {
    return expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.equal(title);
});
```

This is Globals.js -

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

class Globals {
    constructor() {
        this.expect = chai.expect;
        chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    }
}

module.exports = Globals;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`browser` is global variable, you can use it directly without to require it. Thus following line is unnecessary:

```
const browser = require('protractor');
```